# React unable to send email with SendGrid

Tags: reactjs, sendgrid

I am using react to send emails:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.REACT_APP_SENDGRID);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

But I got the following error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send' 
from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. 
Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, 
set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

How do I fix it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Sendgrid won't let you send an email directly using Javascript in the browser.

You will need to have a server set-up and use the server to send the email instead (using your favourite back-end framework/language, Node.js, php, Java, etc.).

The steps for sending a mail will be similar to this:

1. Write email details in the React application
2. Send a POST request to your server endpoint (for example, /sendemail) with the email data (recipient, title, content, etc.)
3. Receive Email data in the server and send it to Sendgrid api

Here is the official **Sendgrid** documentation regarding their CORS policy: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/