# Getting “TypeError: failed to fetch” when sending an email with SendGrid on ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, sendgrid

I am trying to send email with SendGrid in ReactJS project.

This is my componnet:

```
//Email.js
import React from 'react'      

const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
 to: 'aaaaa@gmail.com',
 from: 'bbbb@gmail.com',
 subject: 'This is a test mail',
 text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
 html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};

 sgMail.send(msg).catch(error => {alert(error.toString()); });

export const Email= () => (
        <h1>Email Sending Page</h1>
)
```

When I am trying to run the app with "npm start" on localhost, the email is not sent and I got the error message "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

But, if I am using this code:

```
//Email.js
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
 to: 'aaaaa@gmail.com',
 from: 'bbbb@gmail.com',
 subject: 'This is a test mail',
 text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
 html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};

sgMail.send(msg)
```

and do this command: "node Email.js" the mail is sent. It works only this way and I cannot understand why.

I tried any solution that I could find but nothing works.

(I tried even to put the api_key hardcoded in the code just for the test and I got the same result).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

After looking around a bit I found out that you can't use Sendgrid to send email directly from the browser.

> Sendgrid won't let you send an email directly using Javascript in the
>   browser.
>
> You will need to have a server set-up and use the server to send the
>   email instead (using your favourite back-end framework/language,
>   Node.js, php, Java, etc.).
>
> The steps for sending a mail will be similar to this:
>
> 1. Write email details in the React application
> 2. Send a POST request to
>      your server endpoint (for example, /sendemail) with the email data
>      (recipient, title, content, etc.) Receive Email data in the server and
> 3. send it to Sendgrid api Here is the official Sendgrid documentation
>      regarding their CORS policy:
>      https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/cors/

Source: [React unable to send email with SendGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54797626/react-unable-to-send-email-with-sendgrid)

**EDIT 2**

If you want to implement Sendgrid without actually building and deploying a server, you can use a simple [Firebase function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) which is free to host.

I know this may look intimidating but in reality its pretty easy.  Also I just put this together real quick so if anything doesn't work out for you, shoot me a comment.

1. Follow steps 1-3 on the [getting started page for firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).  It is pretty straightforward and you end up with the firebase tools CLI installed.
2. Navigate to the `functions/` folder inside your project on the command line/terminal.
3. Install the Sendgrid and cors libraries in the functions folder

```
npm i @sendgrid/mail cors
```

4. Add your Sendgrid API key to your firebase environment with the following command in your project:

```
firebase functions:config:set sendgrid.key="THE API KEY"
```

5. Copy this into your `functions/index.js` file:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });
const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

exports.sendEmail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    sgMail.setApiKey(functions.config().sendgrid.api);

    return cors(req, res, () => {
        const { msg } = req.body;

        sgMail.send(msg).catch(error => {
            alert(error.toString());
        });

        res.status(200).send(msg);
    });
});
```

6. Save it and run `firebase deploy --only functions` on the command line.  Your function should now be live at `https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail`
7. Now change your React file to:

```
//Email.js

import React, { useEffect } from 'react'      

export const Email= () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const sendEmail = async() => {
      const msg = {
        to: 'aaaaa@gmail.com',
        from: 'bbbb@gmail.com',
        subject: 'This is a test mail',
        text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
        html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
      }; 

      const response = await fetch(
        'https://us-central1-FIREBASE-PROJECT-ID-HERE.cloudfunctions.net/sendEmail', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(msg),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });

      console.log("response", response);
    }

    sendEmail();
  }, []);

  return <h1>Email Sending Page</h1>
}
```

And thats it!  You basically have a server side function without making a server and its free!

Feel free to ignore this if you don't feel like putting in the work but if you need any help, let me know.

Comment: Ah it looks like it isn't possible, check my edited answer

Comment: Thank you very much. Does all ractJS email libraries has the same behavior? or there are any that can be used for email sending directly within the browser?

Comment: Most libraries require a server request to send emails to prevent spam and hacking.  I'll edit my post again with an easy way to implement Sendgrid emailing without having to run an additional server.

Comment: I added an explanation of the simplest way I know how to send emails in a serverless way, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will definitely try it and let you know.